# Older Nikon body won't work with AF-P lens

Tags: nikon, compatibility, nikon-d50, af-p

I just bought my first camera, a Nikon D50, and the auto mode won't work with my lens. I have a brand new lens, a AF-P NIKKOR 18-55MM DX VR. The only mode that works is M. Any help would be awsome.

[image: new lense]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AF-P lenses are a newer Nikon technology that doesn't work with older Nikon bodies, such as your D50. There is no way to adjust any settings or update firmware to make your camera any more compatible with this lens.

From [Nikon's product page for the lens](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/camera-lenses/af-p-dx-nikkor-18-55mm-f%252f3.5-5.6g-vr.html):

> The number of cameras compatible with both lenses is limited. Even for compatible cameras, firmware update may be required
>
> Fully compatible models: D7500, D5600, D5500, D5300*, D3400, D3300*, D500 and later models
>
> Compatible models with limited functions: D5, D810 series, Df, D750, D7200, D7100, D5200, Nikon 1 series with the FT1
>
> **Incompatible models:** D4 series, D3 series, D2 series, D1 series, D800 series, D700, D610, D600, D300 series, D200, D100, D7000, D5100, D5000, D90, D80, D70 series, D3200, D3100, D3000, D60, **D50**, D40 series, film cameras